# Ocaml Product of two polynomials

Tags: ocaml, polynomial-math

How to compute the product of two polynomials ?

For example: x^3 + 3x^2 +0.2x and 2x^4 + 3

First I made a type

```
Type term = {coefficient:int; name:string; exponent:int};;
Type polynomials = term list;;
```

then I made a function calculate coefficient

```
let product l l' = 
  List.concat (List.map (fun e -> List.map (fun e' -> (e*e')) l'.coefficient)            
l.coefficient);;
```

This is where I get stuck. I guess I can use the same function for exponent as well,but the question is asking writing a polynomials function with one param, which means two polynomials will be in the same variable

Can someone help me out here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be saying that you're asked to write a function to multiply two polynomials, but the function is supposed to have just one parameter. This, indeed, doesn't make a lot of sense.

You can always use a tuple to bundle any number of values into a single value, but there's no reason to do this (that I can see), and it's not idiomatic for OCaml.

Here's a function with one parameter (a pair) that multiplies two ints:

```
# let multiply (a, b) = a * b;;
val multiply : int * int -> int = <fun>
# multiply (8, 7);;
- : int = 56
```

(As a separate comment, the code you give doesn't compile.)